# How to extract buildscript from build.gradle

Tags: java, gradle

I have following buildscript section in my build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        nexusUrl = project.hasProperty("myNexusUrl") ? myNexusUrl : "http://10.199.0.99:8081/repository/maven-public/"
    }
    repositories {
        maven { url nexusUrl }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath group: 'mygroup', name: 'MyGradleLibrary', version: '1.0.1'
    }
}
```

How can I extract this code to external file, so that it doesn't break the build?

Answer (score 0):

Create a plugin from your library and publish it to that Nexus. Then, add this lines in your `settings.gradle`:

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "…"
        }
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }

    resolutionStrategy {
        eachPlugin {
            if (requested.id.namespace == 'mygroup.gradle-library') {
                useModule('mygroup.gradle-library:1.0.1')
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here you state that you want to substitute `mygroup.gradle-library` plugin with `mygroup.gradle-library:1.0.1` dependency.

Then just add a plugin in your `build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'mygroup.gradle-library'
}
```

Now you have you dependency on the build classpath without `buildscript` block.

---

**EDIT**

In order to apply this to *all* your projects, put these lines in [init script](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/init_scripts.html#sec:using_an_init_script) `~/.gradle/init.gradle` (`$GRADLE_USER_HOME/init.gradle`):

```
settingsEvaluated {
    pluginManagement {
        repositories {
            maven {
                url "…"
            }
            gradlePluginPortal()
        }

        resolutionStrategy {
            eachPlugin {
                if (requested.id.namespace == 'mygroup.gradle-library') {
                    useModule('mygroup.gradle-library:1.0.1')
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After that `plugin` blocks should work. However, it will work only for you but not for your teammates, unless they do the same.

If you don't like `plugins` you can still do "global" configuration via init scripts like demonstrated. [Read more](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/BuildListener.html) about the available APIs.

Comment: The point of my question is to remove the boilerplate from all buildscripts and unify it in one place. Your solution looks great. Unfortunately it still leaves a boilerplate which has to be repeated in all buildscripts.

Comment: @MatthiasDanetzky, try my suggestions from the latest edit.

Comment: Thanks a lot - this is a great idea. Unfortunately it will apply to all my projects and I cannot share it via git. I do however use the global properties to make myNexusUrl less rigid.